# DHCP server with ability to update mac address dynamically

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, isc-dhcp

Is there a better way to maintain MAC to IP specification in dhcp with out restarting dhcp service each time when there is an update.

is it possible to use DHCP with database in Linux to save all configuration,so that dhcp just needs to read that from database with out restarting each time.

Comment: What makes you think the information is not already cached, and reread by later invocations of the daemon?  See, eg, `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases` (or as appropriate for your distro).

Comment: I think the question is more about managing static leases / reservations than any cache being lost on restart. Of course I'd argue 2 points. 1) Restarting the service is extremely quick and has practically 0 impact (as all leases are saved as mentioned, and clients will retry if they happen to request DHCP at the exact instant you restart). 2) Generally there is very little need to constantly keep adding/changing/removing static reservations. I'd question the need to make so many frequent changes that restarting the daemon is an actual problem.

Comment: in normal case i dont find any need of constantly updating mac/ip but in our environment where there are lot of vms,this is required.

Comment: If you give us the bigger picture of WHY you need to update the static IP assignments so often, we might be able to give you better suggestions.